# Use one word to express this: be unable to tell "s" and "th" apart

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone cannot tell the pronunciation of "th" and "s" apart. I am sure there's a single word that can express this in the context. But I can't remember it now. Anyone can help?

Comment: I just posted a similar question and this one now may be more specific. I've tried to look it up in the very dictionary where I had met the word long before.

Comment: The only word close to this is *lisp*, which means to be unable to pronounce 's' and to use 'th' instead.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one word that refers to that particular linguistic problem, but cf. the word [shibboleth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth):

> A word or custom whose variations in pronunciation or style can be used to differentiate members of ingroups from those of outgroups. Within the mindset of the ingroup, a connotation or value judgment of correct/incorrect or superior/inferior can be ascribed to the two variants.

Comment: Yeah, _shibboleth_ works here, but as you note it isn't specific to these two phonemes.  _Lisp_ referenced above and on the other post is also not specific.  In Spanish, where the these pronunciation differences distinguish origin, there are the terms _ceceo_ and _seseo_.

Comment: I stand corrected.  _Lisp_ evidently is specific to inability to pronounce sibalents.  The word _sigmatism_ also references this.  This is a problem with articulation, however, and not perception of the sounds.